# Too Many If Statements Inside Factory

Tags: java, c++, refactoring, factory

I am currently developing an application with lots of different design patterns. It needs to follow good practice basically no code smells.

I am using a factory method to print out random types of objects but I have to use 3 if statements, which seems inefficient... What would happen if I wanted to print out 10 different objects? Would one just have to add more if statements is there no other way around this.

** The ultimate use of this particular method in the factory is to just return a random object (1) of ball type.

```
RandomGenerator ranGen = new RandomGenerator();
int randomNumber = ranGen.createRandomNumber(1,3);
if(randomNumber == 1){
     //return smallBall
}
else if(randomNumber ==2){
    //return mediumBall
}
else if(randomNumber == 3){
    //return largeBall
}
```

Comment: Even a switch would have to be repeated several times?

Comment: You could also create an array of different balls and use the random number for the index.

Comment: What type of data is your Ball?

Comment: Its just an example, its an object of pixmap data type.

Comment: The array-/map-based solutions assume it's okay to return a single instance; if, say, you're generating a room full of random balls you'd probably want a *new* instance each time through, which would require modification from what's been presented so far. Since we don't know the ultimate use of this factory it's hard to provide a concrete answer.

Comment: @DaveNewton see edit :)

Comment: Doesn't help; you don't say if you need to generate multiple unique instances.

Comment: @hat_to_the_back, There is no general-purpose answer to your question as it is currently  posed.  Possible answers vary greatly depending on the details of the objects your factory must provide to its clients.  You'll need to get much more specific for your question to be answerable.

Comment: Yes multiple unique instances, with multiple different attribute for each object,

Comment: @JohnBollinger Think of a motorway with different types of vehicles each which have different speeds, different types of drivers etc. All of type vehicle

Comment: If  you need new instances, then there are a number of options, including any of various ways to construct objects from maps of values (e.g., array entries would contain hashes of named property values for the new objects), using a switch as described, move some of the logic into the classes themselves, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach would be to apply the [**prototype pattern**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern).

In the following example, we have a class named `RandomBallFactory` that
creates random (unique) `Ball` instances by cloning registered prototypes.

Advantages:

- We can add new `Ball` subclasses without having to change the `RandomBallFactory` implementation.
- We can create objects of the same type but with different parameters.
- We have no if-statements.

**Java** example:

```
import java.util.*;

abstract class Ball implements Cloneable {
    abstract String getName();
    public Ball clone() {
        Ball ball;
        try {
            ball = (Ball)super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            ball = null;
        }
        return ball;
    }
}

class SmallBall extends Ball {
    public String getName() { return "smallBall"; }
}

class MediumBall extends Ball {
    public String getName() { return "mediumBall"; }
}

class LargeBall extends Ball {
    public String getName() { return "largeBall"; }
}

class RandomBallFactory {
    private final List<Ball> prototypes;

    public RandomBallFactory() {
        prototypes = new ArrayList<Ball>();
    }

    public void registerBall(Ball ball) {
        prototypes.add(ball);
    }

    public Ball createBall() {
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        Integer randomNumber = randomGenerator.nextInt(prototypes.size());
        return prototypes.get(randomNumber).clone();
    }
}

public class TestBalls {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomBallFactory randomBallFactory = new RandomBallFactory();
        randomBallFactory.registerBall(new SmallBall());
        randomBallFactory.registerBall(new MediumBall());
        randomBallFactory.registerBall(new LargeBall());

        Ball ball = randomBallFactory.createBall();
        System.out.println(ball.getName());
    }
}
```

**C++** example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

class Ball {
public:
    Ball() { std::cout << __func__ << std::endl; }
    Ball(Ball& other) { std::cout << __func__ << " copy from " << other.getName() << std::endl; }
    virtual ~Ball() { std::cout << __func__  << std::endl; }
    virtual std::string getName() = 0;
    virtual Ball* clone() = 0;
};

class SmallBall : public Ball {
public:
    std::string getName() { return "smallBall"; }
    Ball* clone() { return new SmallBall(*this); }
};

class MediumBall : public Ball {
public:
    std::string getName() { return "mediumBall"; }
    Ball* clone() { return new MediumBall(*this); }
};

class LargeBall : public Ball {
public:
    std::string getName() { return "largeBall"; }
    Ball* clone() { return new LargeBall(*this); }
};

class RandomBallFactory {
private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Ball> > prototypes;

public:
    void registerBall(std::shared_ptr<Ball> ball_ptr) {
        prototypes.push_back(ball_ptr);
    }

    std::shared_ptr<Ball> createBall() {
        int randomNumber = std::rand() % prototypes.size();
        return std::shared_ptr<Ball>(prototypes.at(randomNumber)->clone());
    }
};

int main(void) {
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    RandomBallFactory randomBallFactory;

    std::shared_ptr<Ball> sb_ptr(std::make_shared<SmallBall>());
    std::shared_ptr<Ball> mb_ptr(std::make_shared<MediumBall>());
    std::shared_ptr<Ball> lb_ptr(std::make_shared<LargeBall>());

    randomBallFactory.registerBall(sb_ptr);
    randomBallFactory.registerBall(mb_ptr);
    randomBallFactory.registerBall(lb_ptr);

    std::shared_ptr<Ball> ball_ptr(randomBallFactory.createBall());
    std::cout << "random Ball is: " << ball_ptr->getName() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: See this is in Java, I can understand where you are coming from here. But I am doing this in c++ and I am not sure what to replace cloneable with etc

Comment: @hat_to_the_back Are you looking for a C++ solution? Are you serious? Why don't you say that the question? Why is the question tagged with Java? Why is your example code not in C++?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `Map`, something like this (assuming that `SmallBall` and others are subclasses of `Ball`):

```
Map<Integer, Ball> balls = new HashMap<Integer, Ball>();

balls.put(1, new SmallBall());
balls.put(2, new MediumBall());
balls.put(3, new LargeBall());

RandomGenerator ranGen = new RandomGenerator();
Integer randomNumber = ranGen.createRandomNumber(1, balls.size());

return balls.get(randomNumber);
```

Note: In this example, the factory method would always return a reference to
one of the three instances, no new objects are created.

If you want multiple unique instances, put concrete Ball-factories into the map:

```
Map<Integer, BallFactory> ballFactories = new HashMap<Integer, BallFactory>();

ballFactories.put(1, new SmallBallFactory());
ballFactories.put(2, new MediumBallFactory());
ballFactories.put(3, new LargeBallFactory());

RandomGenerator ranGen = new RandomGenerator();
Integer randomNumber = ranGen.createRandomNumber(1, balls.size());

return ballFactories.get(randomNumber).createBall();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have at least two likely techniques available to you to provide for random generation of objects without hard-coding a fixed set of alternatives:

1. Randomization of constructor / factory-method parameters, and
2. Use of a randomly-selected builder object from a collection of such objects maintained by the factory.

I'll focus on the latter.  The suggestion to return a random element from a collection of pre-built ones is a special case, wherein the builder objects trivially provide themselves as the generated object.  A more general form might resemble this:

```
interface Builder<T> {
    T createObject();
}

class Factory<T> {
    private final List<Builder<? extends T>> builders = new ArrayList<>();
    private final RandomGenerator ranGen = new RandomGenerator();

    T createRandomObject() {
        int randomNumber = ranGen.createRandomNumber(0, builders.size() - 1);

        return builders.get(randomNumber).createObject();
    }

    // Not shown: mechanisms for managing the available Builder objects
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution is to use a `switch` statement, something like:

```
int randomNumber = ranGen.createRandomNumber(1,3);
switch (randomNumber) {
    case 1:
        // return smallBall
        break;
    case 2:
        // return mediumBall
        break;
    case 3:
        // return largeBall
        break;
    default:
        // handle non-expected value
        break;
}
```

Comment: Although substituting a `switch` statement with N cases for N `if` / `else if` blocks answers the literal question posed, it doesn't address the underlying issues of scalability and maintainability to which the OP alludes.

Comment: Yes this is correct. What if I had 20 different objects of the same type?

Comment: @hat_to_the_back Then it depends on what the actual use-case is. Do the different objects have a different set of properties (e.g., that you could pass to a constructor)? Etc.

Comment: Referring to the above example each ball will have the same attributes eg, size, bouncyness, colour... but theese will vary eg one will be bigger than the other